# Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

Tags: php

When I process the code below , i always got this error : " Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' ". Can anyone please help me with this? I'm new in php so please bear with me.Thank you in advance.

```
  //updating conversation members
 function update_cmembers($nc_id,$ids){


$r = "DELETE FROM nc_members WHERE nc_id = '$nc_id' ";

mysql_query($r) or die(mysql_error());


$values = array("($nc_id,{$_SESSION['id']},UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),0,1)");


foreach($ids as $id){

    $id=(int)$id;

    $values[] = "($nc_id,$id,0,0,0)";

}

$sql = "INSERT INTO nc_members      (nc_id,user_id,nc_last_view,nc_deleted,nc_rank) VALUES " . implode(",",$values);

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Check `$sql`. You will get what is wrong.

Comment: i have used that code (except for the delete part) when i am creating a new message and it's working fine.. but when i use it in this... i got that error.. can you please explain further how i can debug my code?

Comment: maybe $_SESSION['id'] is an array ? Does the DELETE statement work ? Try to var_dump or echo the $sql before quering it.

Answer (score 1):

It is throwing error because you are passing an associative array to implode function. So the implode function distributes them to multiple arrays and passing them as values.
Please remove this code between $values array and the sql statement.

```
foreach($ids as $id){

     $id=(int)$id;
     $values[] = "($nc_id,$id,0,0,0)";

}
```

As this code is converting the $value array to an associative array.

Comment: Try like this: $values =                                                            array("$nc_id,{$_SESSION['id']},UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),0,1");

$sql = "INSERT INTO nc_members      (nc_id,user_id,nc_last_view,nc_deleted,nc_rank) VALUES (" . implode(",",$values).")";

Answer (score 0):

change `$values = array("($nc_id,{$_SESSION['id']},UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),0,1)");`
to this :

> `$values = array($nc_id,$_SESSION['id'],UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),0,1));

and change

`$sql = "INSERT INTO nc_members      (nc_id,user_id,nc_last_view,nc_deleted,nc_rank) VALUES " . implode(",",$values);`
 to:

> `$sql = "INSERT INTO nc_members      (nc_id,user_id,nc_last_view,nc_deleted,nc_rank) VALUES (" . implode(',',$values).")"`

Comment: I mean is there any new records?